# How can I easily check whether the user submitting a query belongs to them or not in .net core?

Tags: asp.net, api, .net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

**Authorization Set**

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MustNutritionist", policy =>
                  policy.RequireClaim("nutritionistId"));
        });
```

**Controller**

NutritionistUpdateModel have id field.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MustNutritionist")]

    public BaseResponseModel PostEdit([FromForm] NutritionistUpdateModel nutritionistUpdateModel)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = nutritionistService.EditNutritionist(nutritionistUpdateModel);
            if (result)
            {
                return new SuccessResponseModel<bool>(result);

            }
            else
            {
                return new BaseResponseModel(ReadOnlyValues.NutritionistNotFound);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new BaseResponseModel(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Token Generation Claim**

```
claims.Add(new Claim("nutritionistId", nutritionistId.ToString()));
```

**Problem**

I want to check equation of NutritionistUpdateModel.Id and Claims.nutritionistId. I can check with below code.But i must write lots of if else statement.Is there any easy way ?

```
private bool ChechNutritionistAuthorize(int nutritionistId)
{
    var currentUser = HttpContext.User;
    var nutritionistIdClaim=Int32.Parse(currentUser.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "NutritionistId").Value);
    if (nutritionistIdClaim == nutritionistId)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is query do you want submit?

Comment: Yes,i used HttpPost method .I want to update user datas.

Answer (score 0):

Using extension method like this

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static bool ValidateNutritionistId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal, int nutritionistId)
        {
            if (principal == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
            int.TryParse(principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "NutritionistId").Value, out int nutritionistIdClaim);
            return nutritionistIdClaim == nutritionistId;
        }


    }
```

and you can use like this

```
HttpContext.User.ValidateNutritionistId(your id here )
```

and you also need to add using statement and reuse same method in all of your Controllers

Comment: This is very useful but this code does not fulfill the function I want. Because i must write if else statements in controller methods.